# Azure ML free trial: how to submit pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using a free trial account on MS Azure and I'm following this tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-designer-automobile-price-train-score

I'm stuck when I try to "submit the pipeline".

The reason seems to be that I can't create a compute instance or a training cluster on a free plan.
I still have 200USDs of free credits. I guess there must be a solution?

---

Error messages:

```
Invalid graph: The pipeline compute target is invalid.

400: Compute Test3 in state Failed, which is not able to use

Compute instance: creation failed
The specified subscription has a total vCPU quota of 0 and is less than the requested compute training cluster and/or compute instance's min nodes of 1 which maps to 4 vCPUs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the announcement from MS Team regarding this:

https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

All the free trials will not work as of now

Comment: Please don't post this as an answer. This is a transient issue, very specific to resource governance during the covid-19 situation, which has now been asked in various forms elsewhere (and it's not a programming question, and off-topic for Stack Overflow). Just post that link as a comment and vote to close. And close-vote any other question with a similar issue (along with an explanatory comment if you wish, if there's not one already).

Comment: Noted, will do  from now on